# Blender extrude causing distortion of model

Tags: mesh, modifiers, extrude

I have a problem with the extrude function. When trying to extrude a certain limb for a character, the inner part of the model is getting distorted as shown in the image. How do I fix this issue?

Before Extrusion:
[image]

After Extrusion(notice the inner part of the hand is distorted):
[image]

Comment: Hello, it might be worth adding you're using a combination of skin + subdivision surface modifiers here. Judging by the abrupt end of the limb in the 1st picture, I'd say you have 2 vertices on the same spot here. In edit mode select everything and right click > merge > By distance

Comment: It worked, thanks man.